# ActivityCompat.OnRequestPermissionsResultCallback cannot be resolvet to a type

Tags: android, eclipse, permissions, lib

I using Eclipse, the mindSdkVersion of my project is 19 and the targetSdkVersion is 23. Which libraries belongs to (or I need to use) for eliminating the mentioned error in the "Title"? I already tried "support-v4-19.1.0.jar" and "support-v13-19.1.0.jar" but the error is constantly appeared. I would like to use dynamically ask the user allow permission or not for the external storage.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Runtime permissions were introduced in Android 6 (API 23). How do you have target SDK version greater than compile SDK version in the first place? (Major version of support libs has to equal compile SDK version.)

Comment: Where can I located this file?

Comment: First update tools and support libs repository in the SDK manager, then https://developer.android.com/studio/intro/migrate.html Eclipse is no longer officially supported. Androdi Studio will then give you hints.

Comment: Who the hell is using Eclipse for developing Android apps anymore...

Comment: Stop using eclipse please.

Comment: soon or later you will have to move to Android Studio. And while you don't move, you will suffer from problems, which nobody is able to help you with because **nobody is using eclipse**.

Comment: also you should use support libraries version not lower than your targetSDK version (23). As I can see, you try to use 19.1. It's wrong.

Comment: I have one (this) project is which in Eclipse. The other projects in AndroidStudio. Is there a location where I can found the libraries? In AndroidStudio this is a simple thing, I add into dependencies in gradle.

Comment: I would appreciate if someone explain me which libraries should use in Eclipse for runtime permissions and where can I download that? I tried support libraries (sdk\extras\android\m2repository\com\android\support\support-v4 and appcompat-v7) for versions 19 and 23 but always had an error.